# SaSS syntax for attribute with class inside?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have style for `.post`, `.share`, `.tag` like this:

```
.post {
  ... // style for .post
}
.share {
  ... // style for .share
}
.post {
  ... //style for .tag
}
```

So, I want style for `a.post`, `a.share`, `a.tag`. It's any way to write it inside `.post`, `.share`, `.tag` syntax above? Or I have to write it in separate outside like:

```
a.post {}
a.share {}
a.tag {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation on the ampersand `#{&}` and also need `@at-root` for nested concatenated selectors.

```
.post {
    @at-root a#{&} {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://gist.github.com/andorx/1931801d05e95c9a838e15b5d1cb4bec)